# Floating point subtraction works inconsistently

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64

Im trying to subtract two floating point numbers without using floating point instructions but right now it only works with some numbers, for example 10.9 - 2.5 results in 8.4 which is correct but 5.7 - 2.5 results in 7.2.

I make the exponents even and then subtract the mantissas and then combine them.
For now the sign is automatically 0 because I first want to make it work with positive numbers

Here is the code:

```
; expands a floating point number into sign, exponent and fraction
%macro expand 1
    push rax
    mov eax, %1
    rol eax, 1
    mov byte [sign], al
    and byte [sign], 1
    rol eax, 8
    mov byte [exponent], al
    shr eax, 9
    or eax, 800000h
    mov dword [fraction], eax
    pop rax
%endmacro

; combines sign, exponent and fraction to make a floating point number
%macro combine 1
    push rsi
    push rcx
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rdx
    mov esi, %1
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov eax, [fraction]
    mov ebx, [exponent]
    mov edx, [sign]
    shrd ecx, eax, 23
    shrd ecx, ebx, 8
    shrd ecx, edx, 1
    mov dword [esi], ecx
    pop rdx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    pop rcx
    pop rsi
%endmacro

section .bss 
    result resd 1

section .data
    source dd 5.7
    source2 dd 2.5

section .text
    global _start 

    _start:
        xor ebx, ebx
        expand [source]
        ; store expanded parts in these registers
        mov bl, [exponent]
        mov eax, [fraction]
        mov cl, [sign]
        expand [source2]

        ; make exponents even
        while:
            cmp [exponent], bl
            jnl endwhile
            inc byte [exponent]
            shr dword [fraction], 1
            jmp while
        endwhile:

        while2:
            cmp bl, [exponent]
            jnl endwhile2
            inc bl
            shr eax, 1
            jmp while
        endwhile2:


        ; make operand 2 negative and then add them together
        neg dword [fraction]
        add eax, dword [fraction]
        mov [fraction], eax
        mov [exponent], bl
        mov byte [sign], 0
        combine result
        mov edx, [result]

        exit
```

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping this in a debugger?  Your source code doesn't define the labels `fraction`/`exponent`/`sign`.  Also, shifting 1 bit at a time avoids problems if the difference in exponents is large enough to shift out all the bits, so I guess get it working the slow way first, but x86 does have variable-count shifts.  See earlier revisions of this codegolf answer ([Bitwise XOR of floats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247235)) which subtracted exponents in ECX, and compared to see if it was more than the mantissa width.

Comment: That software-float XOR problem is very much like soft-FP add/sub.  It truncates instead of rounding to nearest, so yeah, just shifting out mantissa bits in the float with smaller magnitude works.

Comment: ok thanks, i have another question. How can I set the exponent for example in 10.1 - 9.9? The result is 0.2 and the exponent is 124, but 10.1 and 9.9 both have an exponent of 130, so how am i supposed to get 124 from that?

Comment: Like in that SO Q&A, you have renormalize after subtraction (potentially a lot of high zero bits in the mantissa, meaning few significant digits left; this is called "catastrophic cancellation" because the result doesn't have very much precision.)  Shift the mantissa until there's a leading 1 again.  Like `lzcnt` or 31-`bsr` to get a shift count, and subtract that from the exponent.

Comment: for example the 10.1 - 9.9, i can just subtract their fractions right away because the exponents are same right?
After that the fraction is 110011001100110100 and the fraction of 0.2 is 10011001100110011001101 so it seems it would have to be shifted to the left once, why? So then you would have to subtract 1 from the exponent is that correct? Then the exponent would be 129, when it should be 124

Comment: `110011001100110100` is several bits shorter than `10011001100110011001101`.  I think you're omitting leading zeros.  (I think as long as you deal with the signs so you're subtracting the smaller-magnitude from the larger-magnitude, you'll have leading zeros in the mantissa requiring renormalization, or you won't if borrow doesn't propagate up and clear the high mantissa bits.  But you won't have non-significant leading 1s to deal with, so it is I think always like the XOR case on code-golf.  Which is not always easy, there are corner cases like creating 0.0, or subnormals...)

Comment: I just implemented a loop that shifts the mantissa until there's a leading 1 again, and the loop iterated only once. So its probably clearing the high bits. What do you mean by smaller and larger magnitude? Shouldn't i just subtract operator 1 from operator 2?

Comment: Now it iterates 14 times, at the start of the program i forgot to zero out the 32 bit register that will hold the result of the fraction. 
But still 14 times is too many, 130 - 14 is not 124, which is the exponent of 0.2

Comment: If you did `9.9 - 10.1` in that order, your mantissa subtraction would produce a carry-out, and all the high bits would be `1`s.  (i.e. 2's complement negative, but the mantissa is unsigned, not 2's complement.)

Comment: You're probably shifting it to the top of a 32-bit register, instead of shifting it to the top of the 24-bit mantissa field (which is then encoded in a 23-bit field with the leading 1 implied by the exponent).  Shifting to the top of a register lets you use SF to detect when it becomes 1, but if you're using `bsr` to calculate a shift-count, that doesn't matter.

Comment: I did `10.1 - 9.9`, and right now im shifting it to the top of a 32 bit register, so it iterates 14 times, but how can I shift it to the top of the 24 bit mantissa field? If I dont zero out the 32 bit register it will only iterate once

Comment: You could work with mantissas left-shifted so the top bit *is* at the top of a register.  e.g. `and eax, -(1<<9)` instead of `shr eax,9`.  That would leave room to keep some less-significant bits in the lower-exponent number, instead of losing them right away on right shifting.  That would maybe let you round to nearest instead of truncating (or away from zero with subtraction discarding input bits)

Comment: Obviously if you want to detect bit #24 becoming 1, you `test eax, 1<<24` / `jz still_denormal`, so that's the simplest change.  And yes, you'd want to zero high garbage in the register; you need to at some point to merge back in the exponent and sign.

Comment: what about how do I set the sign?

Comment: if the result is negative i need to remove the leading 1 bits, but how will i know if the result will be negative?

Comment: FP is a sign/magnitude format. There's a completely separate sign bit.  You have to look at your input signs to figure out if you're adding or subtracting magnitudes, and what the sign of the result will be.  (Or since you have extra bits in a register, maybe apply the signs to the magnitudes to make one of them 2's complement negative so you can always add?  That may not reduce the number of conditions to deal with.)  Note that the exponent bias makes it possible to use integer compares on the whole FP bit-pattern (except for NaNs), after zeroing sign bits.